# is the Change Listener added only once or many time

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, changelistener

I'm trying to create a media player in javafx8, and for that I created a button and set it onAction to add a change listener to the stage fullscreen property and make the stage full screen if it's not and exit the full screen if it's already.

```
public void setFullScreen(ActionEven event) {
    Stage stage = ((Stage) containerBorderPane.getScene().getWindow());
    stage.fullScreenProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            setUpMenuBar(stage.isFullScreen())
    );
    stage.setFullScreen(!stage.isFullScreen());
}
```

this method is called every time I click the button, so is this "Change Listener" added to fullScreenProperty multiple times or just once?

Answer (score 0):

Every time `setFullScreen` is invoked you create a *new* `ChangeListener` and register it with the property. So you aren't adding "this" `ChangeListener` each time but a *different* `ChangeListener` each time.

Even if you did pass the *same* `ChangeListener` to `addListener` each time it would still be added multiple times. From the documentation of `ObservableValue.addListener(ChangeListener)` (**emphasis** mine):

> Adds a ChangeListener which will be notified whenever the value of the ObservableValue changes. **If the same listener is added more than once, then it will be notified more than once. That is, no check is made to ensure uniqueness.**